# How do I prevent all the slides in a section slide from appearing on load in ScrollMagic?

Tags: javascript, html, gsap, scrollmagic

I've recently been using ScrollMagic, and so far it's been easy to use. However, after finishing my section slides i've noticed that whenever I load the page at the section slide top, all the slides will be visible until I update it. Returning back to the top will only show the first slide as intended? Is there a way to force update the section slides to prevent this?

[faulty section slides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5wSO.png)

Javascript:

```js
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// define movement of panels
var wipeAnimation = new TimelineMax()
    .fromTo("#panel1", {x:  "0%"} , {x: "100%", ease: Linear.easeNone}, 0)  // in from right
    .fromTo("#panel2", {x: "-100%"} , {x: "0%", ease: Linear.easeNone}, 0)  // in from left
    .fromTo("#panel2", {x:  "0%"} , {x: "100%", ease: Linear.easeNone}, 1)  // in from right
    .fromTo("#panel3", {x: "-100%"} , {x: "0%", ease: Linear.easeNone}, 1);  // in from left

// create scene to pin and link animation
new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: ".main",
        triggerHook: "onLeave",
        duration: "300%"
    })
    .on("start", function (event) {
    })
    .setPin(".main")
    .setTween(wipeAnimation)
    .addTo(controller);
```

...and HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Website</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div id="panel1" class="panel">
        <p>redacted</p>
      </div>

      <div id="panel2" class="panel">
        <p>redacted</p>
      </div>
      
      <div id="panel3" class="panel">
        <p>redacted</p>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tried using both enter and start events to trigger

```
scene.update(true);
```

, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add your CSS as well?

Comment: nvm, fixed it by creating a slide container and placed all other slides out of view, and just moved the slide container. hopefully this helps any noobs who view this